# Directus pagination webhook / API url in flow

Tags: directus, directus-flows

I created a flow with a webhook that takes data from an external API. I would like to know how to implement pagination as the API only returns the first 100 results.

In the first flow i add a Manual trigger, a Webhook with url and GET option to external API then a send the data of API to another flow for loop the item of API.

I think that i must insert a custom script after the webhook.

Thank you :)